# Question about proportionally rules

Tags: homework-and-exercises, astrophysics, differentiation, binary-stars

I don't think context is needed but to make sure: I'm doing a homework exercise on binary system. P is the orbital period and E the energy of the system. The following is in the solution when trying to calculate $\dot P / P$:

> Since $P\propto a^{3/2}\propto E^{-3/2}$, we have $\frac{\dot P}{P}=-\frac{3}{2}\frac{\dot E}{E}.$

I don't understand the steps here. I understand that if a is proportional to b, then the derivative of a divided by a is equal to the derivative of b divided by b. b and a are proportional with regard to t so by dividing by the derivative 'clears' the other factors in a and b making them equal. What I don't understand is where the -3/2 term comes from. Maybe my whole understanding, what I explained earlier, is a bit wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Caspertijmen1, could you edit your question to include the original exercise? That does often provide useful context.

Comment: @DavidZ Seems like its a clarification question about a step in the solutions of the exercise, and not a question about the exercise itself. Not sure if that would still violate homework policy

Comment: @DannyKong Indeed, a question asking for clarification about a step in the solution, but which does not ask for the solution of the original exercise nor for help solving the exercise, is permitted under our homework policy. I agree that this seems like that type of question. But it should still give the original exercise for context.

Comment: @DavidZ Someone answered the question, but it seems it was deleted (?). Do you want me to include the original exercise? It is a pretty long question and I feel it is not really that relevant to the question I asked.

Comment: @Caspertijmen1 The deleted answer was mine, but it would be good to edit the beginning of the question so that it is clear what you are asking, so that future readers can find this question if they have a similar problem.

Comment: @Caspertijmen1 Yes, it would be great if you could include the original exercise. If it's really long (like, if it would _more than_ double the length of your post) then I suppose you can summarize it rather than quoting the entire thing.